# Connection Timed out Page

Tags: java

I have a Java Web application that generates a report and I have the ability to export that report to an excel file, problem is whenever I generate it as an excel file a "Connection Timed Out" page is being displayed on a firefox web browser.

Basically I have no idea why is this happening, I see no problems in my code could it be server issues or the amount of data I'm generating?  Also no error logs are being displayed.

Any advise, suggestions would be of great help thanks.

Comment: Would you please post a code sample?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It sounds like the request is taking too long, and being timed out. Basically it's taking too long to generate the report. This could be too long for the client, the app server or the webserver (if you have a separate webserver).  You have a few options:

- Find out where the timeout settings are in the Application Server and increase them
- Speed up your report writing code so it doesn't take as long
- Make the report writer an asyncronous job (eg by kicking of the report generation in a new thread), and have the client pole the server until it's finished, then request the file.

Update based on OP comment:
Regarding the last suggestion:
If the report's generated by another thread, the current request will return before the report is generated, so the browser won't have to wait at all. However, this is quite a large amount of work because you have to have a way for the client-side code to find out when the report is finished. Also, you are not supposed to launch your own threads from a Servlet.

Maybe you can make the original request via AJAX, or in an iFrame? This way the restrictive timeout threshold may not be in effect.

Comment: Hi... Sorry for commenting on very late.. was on vacation.. the third option is really good and works... Although currently i an using firefox version 29.. and it seems im still getting the page timed out only in this version.. older versions are doing fine. According to mozilla support firefox now has a response timeout of 5mins so even though if its in another thread and it generates longer yhan 5 mins.. i still get the error... What approach can i use if its a browser issue?

Comment: Forgot to say thanks for the first three suggestions ^_^